# Indexing a computed column in sql states it is non-deterministic and fails

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created the following computed column

```
ALTER TABLE 
[users] ADD [LastNameCleaned] AS ([dbo].[ConvertAccents]([lastname]))
```

I want to add an index to LastNameCleaned but I am getting an error that the column is non-deterministic.

The `[ConvertAccents]` function strips diacritics from the string and returns the cleaned string.

I noticed that `WITH SCHEMEBINDING` is recommended to be added to the function under the `RETURN` and that should make it deterministic but it is not working for me.

I am trying to work out what I am missing.

I would also like to `PERSIST` the computed column but again because the call back from the `[ConvertAccents]` function it states it is non-deterministic and will not allow me to do it.

Code for ConvertAccents

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertAccents (@Text nvarchar(200))
RETURNS nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @TempString nvarchar(200)
  --set @TempString = REPLACE(@TempString,'øß', 'oss')
  set @TempString = (CONVERT(varchar(200), @Text) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI) 
  set @TempString = REPLACE(@TempString,'o?', 'oss')
  set @TempString = LOWER(@TempString)

  return @TempString
END
GO
```

Comment: What is the DDL of `[dbo].[ConvertAccents]`? If it is using any functions not listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-ver15#built-in-function-determinism) it is not deterministic, and so cannot be indexed, as it cannot be persisted.

Comment: Oh Zohar such a helpful comment well done

Comment: @Larnu I have put the code in the edit for the convert function. I am using Convert, Replace and lower. would there be another way I could achieve what is in the code to enable it to be deterministic?

Comment: @Nick was you able to add an index to the computed column as that was the issue

Comment: @markblue777 apologies, I missed that point. Comment deleted...

Comment: @markblue777 it seems to be the `COLLATE` that is making it non-deterministic, although I can't really understand why that would be the case... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=0f09dfb6ada5d8041d7abec67bd9c0d3

Comment: The problem is the `CONVERT` here, not `COLLATE`, @Nick . `COLLATE` is a string function, and as per the link given above is deterministic. `CONVERT`, on the other hand, is not deterministic.

Comment: @Larnu if you look at my demo it has a convert and is working fine. Only when you uncomment the collate does it become non-deterministic. So I guess it's actually the combination of both which is the problem.

Comment: @Nick try with `COLLATE`: [db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=d3a420e0e7934b04456919df84126489). `CONVERT` *can* be deterministic but has some caveats with it. Using `CONVERT` with `COLLATE` appears to make it non-determinitic, which is odd, as it isn't documented.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the problem is the usage of `Convert` - if that is removed, the function becomes deterministic and the computed column can be marked as persisted and indexed. You also need to add `WITH SCHEMABINDING` to the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertAccents (@Text nvarchar(200))
RETURNS nvarchar(200)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  declare @TempString nvarchar(200) 
  set @TempString = @Text COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI
  set @TempString = REPLACE(@TempString,'øß', 'oss')
  set @TempString = LOWER(@TempString)

  return @TempString
END
```

Having said that, for just this replace you can do that all with a single line, without a user-defined function altogether:

```
create table users (
    LastName nvarchar(200),
    LastNameCleaned AS (LOWER(REPLACE(lastname COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI,'øß', 'oss'))) persisted
)
```

Comment: The trouble is, is that if i remove convert the accents are not removed from the text

Comment: I don't recommend the "single line solution". If you try to create a unique nonclustered index on that, for example, you'll get the warning: `Warning! The maximum key length for a nonclustered index is 1700 bytes. The index 'ixU_Users_LastNameCleaned' has maximum length of 8000 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.`

Comment: The column won't even have a length longer than 200, due to the data type of `LastName`, @AlwaysLearning , but you could use `LEFT(...,200)` on the expression to remove the error.

Comment: @Larnu given LastName stays at nvarchar(200), yes, but: `select name,max_length from sys.columns where object_id=object_id(N'dbo.Users');` shows it capable of consuming up to 8,000 bytes - thus the warning message.

Comment: Yes, because `COLLATE` implicitly turns it into an `nvarchar(4000)` on it's own @AlwaysLearning . You can use `LEFT` to implicitly cast it back to an `nvarchar(200)`. Notice the data types in this fiddle: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=7538de1ff2ff521543a93cc99e550b58). Putting the index on `LastName` won't cause the error, and returning `LastNameCleaned` back to a `nvarchar(200)` get's rid of the error too. We know, as well, that no truncation will occur so it is completely safe.

Comment: @Larnu try again, mate. It's not the `COLLATE` that causes it, it's the `REPLACE`.

Comment: OK, wrong, function, my point is still the same, `LEFT` fixes the error you speak of, @AlwaysLearning , you *can't* dispute that and i don't know why you are? The calculated value of `LastNameCleaned` will **never** be longer than 200 characters, and 400 bytes, so `LEFT` is more than safe.

Comment: @Larnu I always dispute people giving downright wrong advice.

Comment: There are no downvotes here, @AlwaysLearning . I really don't see you're point here, so i'm disengaging...